# Login Form Failure jQuery + Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to refresh the page  upon successful login in the Ajax script but the page is not refreshed. I am forced to refresh the page manually and only then will it appear to be logged in. Thanks in advance for any help, it is much appreciated.

This is the login script for ajax;

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#what").click(function() {
        var email = $("#emailLogin").val();
        var password = $("#passwordLogin").val();
        var dataString = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "authenticate.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response){                
                //alert (response);
                if (response == 0) {
                $("#problem").html("Please enter correct details");
                            } else {
                    window.location = "index.php";
                }
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

This is the php script for validating the form

```
// authenticate.php

session_start();
require_once "database.php";
db_connect();
require_once "auth.php";


$user_id = credentials_valid($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);

if($user_id){
  log_in($user_id);
  if($_SESSION['redirect_to']){
    header("Location: " . $_SESSION['redirect_to']);
    unset($_SESSION['redirect_to']);
  }else{
    header("Location: index.php");
  }

}else{
  echo "0";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you need to refresh the page because you post with JQuery and the php function only returns some data.

You have 2 alternatives:

1. Post the classic way (form submit)
2. Redirect from javascript using window.location='url';

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with javascript. AJAX requests can't redirect user's browsers

```
if (response == 0) {
    $("#problem").html("Please enter correct details");
} else {
    window.location = "/index.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i see you are redirecting in the js if the response is not equal to 0, and in the php you are redirecting if the log-in failed. also the server side redirecting is not working with ajax, you have to redirect it with `window.location.href = 'url'` also you may send the code status in the response but not writing it yourself.